# LLDB with Python problem: set PATH exclusively for one executable?

Tags: bash, path, lldb

Is there a way of set the PATH variable exclusively for one executable in bash script?

I want to do so because somehow macOS's LLDB requires system-intalled Python, not my Anaconda-managed Python, therefore I need to ensure `/usr/bin` is at the beginning of `PATH`. But I prefer Anaconda-managed Python for everyday use, so I don't want to set `PATH` permanently just to accommodate LLDB.

Temporarily manually writing `PATH` before and after using LLDB is cumbersome, so I'm thinking about some kind of wrapper script or alias that automates this routine.

P.S. LLDB has the same problem with Homebrew-managed Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are, by definition, per-process. Each process has a copy of the environment which it can modify for its own reasons.

To override the `PATH` just for a single invocation, all `sh`-compatible shells allow you to say

```
PATH=newvalue executable with arguments
```

which sets `PATH` to `newvalue` for the duration of the execution of `executable with arguments`, then reverts the value back to its previous state (the current value, or unset if it was unset).

If you want to override something in the environment every time you execute something, you need a wrapper.  Assuming you have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, you could install this in `/usr/local/bin/something` to override `/usr/bin/something` with a wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=newvalue
exec /usr/bin/something "$@"
```

Remember `chmod a+x` and of course you need to be `root` to have write access to this directory in the first place.

For your private needs, a shell function in your `.profile` or similar is sufficient.

```
something () {
    PATH=newvalue command something "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could just set an alias: `alias lldb='PATH=/usr/bin lldb'`